# Combine list of lists of tuples with different lengths

Tags: python, merge, tuples, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I'm having a problem to combine list of lists of tuples, and the main problem comes from different sizes of those tuples. I'm also trying to do it "pythonic" way, which isn't very easy.

What I actually have is a list of objects, having coordinates given in tuple.
Objects (let's say: lines) always have start and end as (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), they also usually have some "path". The problem is that "path" is sometimes empty and in general number of points on the path is different.

```
start=[ (3,5), (23,50), (5,12), (51,33), (43,1)]
end = [(23,19), (7,2), (34,4),  (8,30), (20,10)]
path=[[(10,7),(14,9),(18,15)],
      [],
      [(15,7)],
      [(42,32),(20,31)],
      [(30,7)]]
```

Expected result should look like this:

```
whole_path = [[(3,5),(10,7),(14,9),(18,15),(23,19)],
              [(23,50),(7,2)],
              [(5,12),(15,7),(34,4)],
              [(51,33),(42,32),(20,31),(8,30)],
              [(43,1),(30,7),(20,10)]]
```

I was trying to use zip - it works well for similar size items in start/end/paths lists but not with their differences.
Promising solutions might come with use `path.insert(0,start)` and `path.extend([end])`, but I couldn't make that working, there is also an option to put that into two loops, but it doesn't look well and... it's not very "pythonic".
So: any suggestions would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with `zip` and `*`-unpacking of the variable-length path element is reasonably clean:

```
from pprint import pprint

start=[ (3,5), (23,50), (5,12), (51,33), (43,1)]
end = [(23,19), (7,2), (34,4),  (8,30), (20,10)]
path=[[(10,7),(14,9),(18,15)],
      [],
      [(15,7)],
      [(42,32),(20,31)],
      [(30,7)]]

whole_path = [[s, *p, e] for s, p, e in zip(start, path, end)]
pprint(whole_path)
```

giving the required:

```
[[(3, 5), (10, 7), (14, 9), (18, 15), (23, 19)],
 [(23, 50), (7, 2)],
 [(5, 12), (15, 7), (34, 4)],
 [(51, 33), (42, 32), (20, 31), (8, 30)],
 [(43, 1), (30, 7), (20, 10)]]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect solution I was looking for, simple and so "pythonic"! I knew there is something like *p that can be used to "unzip" data, but I never used this syntax.